# Why AnyVal (Int, Double) cannot be the actual parameter of scala.Serializable parameter

Tags: scala, serializable

Does AnyVal (Int, Double) extend scala.Serializable and what is the different between java.io.Serializable and scala.Serializable as a method parameter in Scala?

```
def f (p : scala.Serializable): Unit = {}
def g (p : java.io.Serializable): Unit = {}
//f(1) Type mismatch, expected:Serializable,actual:Int 
g(1) //It works
```

The Scala doc says that Int is a subType of scala.Serializable(http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.6/index.html#scala.Serializable).However,scala.Serializable extends java.io.Serializable. so I think the value of Int is kind type of scala.Serializable and java.io.Serializable and both can be the parameter above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `Int` does not extend Serializable. The link (from known subclasses) is [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.6/index.html#scala.math.Ordering$$Int$) one which is just an `Ordering[Int]` implicit instance. `Int` and `AnyVal` are defined like so:

```scala
final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal
abstract class AnyVal extends Any
```

So as you can see, they're not `java.io.Serializable` or `scala.Serializable`.

As for why the code works, check out `scala.Predef` to find the implicit conversion from `scala.Int` to `java.lang.Integer` (which implements `java.io.Serializable`). And `scala.Predef` is imported implicitly so that's why it works:

```scala
object Predef {
  ...
  implicit def int2Integer(x: Int) = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(x)
  ...
}
```

So behind the scene your code is the following:

```scala
g(1)

// After the implicit conversion g(1) is actually:
g(Integer.valueOf(1))
```

I hope this clears up the confusion, I've been there myself :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part. But to put it in a nutshell, `scala.Int` and `scala.math.Ordering.Int` are really different. `scala.Int` is a class why the latter is just a singleton instance of `Ordering[Int]`. The `Int` parameter type in the latter is actually `scala.Int`.